# Java Spring JPA Query Error: '(',<expression>,FUNCTION or identifier expected, got '('

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

***I'm asking the question cuz all the related posts i found are not answered***

[Error at line 21 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0NT0.png)
Hello guys I need some help with this Query, at line 21 I got an error that says " '(',, FUNCTION or identifier expected, got '(' "
but I can't seem to find anything wrong here, when I was doing in on MySQL WorkBench scripts was working fine.. but when I transfer it to the Query it gives me that error, I've counted all the brackets they are equal so I don't really know what's going on here. I would be happy if someone manages to tell me what's wrong here ty.

Script tested at MySQL Workbench:
The script actually works perfectly at MySQL but when I transfer it to Intellij it drops error :/

```
SELECT * FROM rooms r
WHERE (r.people >= 10 AND r.id NOT IN(SELECT rr.room_id FROM reservations rr))
OR (r.people >= 10 AND r.id IN (SELECT rr.room_id FROM reservations rr 
WHERE (rr.start_date NOT BETWEEN '2022-03-15' AND '2022-03-31' ) 
AND (rr.end_date NOT BETWEEN '2022-03-15' AND '2022-03-31')))
OR(r.people >= 10 AND r.id IN(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reservations rr
WHERE (rr.start_date BETWEEN '2022-03-15' AND '2022-03-31') AND (rr.end_date BETWEEN '2022-03-15' AND '2022-03-31')
GROUP BY rr.room_id
HAVING COUNT(rr.room_id) < r.`count`
ORDER BY r.id))
```

Query From Intellij

```
@Query(value = "SELECT r FROM Room r " +
        "WHERE (r.people >= ?3 AND r.id NOT IN (SELECT rr.room_id FROM Reservation rr))" +
        "OR (r.people >= ?3 AND r.id IN (SELECT rr.room_id FROM Reservation rr " +
        "WHERE (rr.start_date NOT BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2) AND (rr.end_date NOT BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2))) " +
        "OR (r.people >= ?3 AND r.id IN (SELECT COUNT (rr.room_id) FROM Reservation rr" +
        "WHERE (rr.start_date BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2) AND (rr.end_date BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2)" +
        "GROUP BY rr.room_id" +
        "HAVING COUNT(rr.room_id) < r.count" +
        "ORDER BY r.id))")
```

Comment: Space characters are missing before most of your ending double-quotes, like here `"OR (r.people >= ?3 AND r.id IN (SELECT COUNT (rr.room_id) FROM Reservation rr"` , this will end up as a wrong query containing `FROM Reservation rrWHERE` for instance.

Comment: Thanks, Arnaud, I fixed the spaces, I didn't know that really affect the code, but hey every day u learn something new :P but I still get the same error unfortunately after the spaces too.

Comment: *The script actually works perfectly* Really? in the last condition you compare `r.id` with `COUNT(*)`...

Comment: Akina, thanks for showing this to me, I'm kind of new to MySQL scripting so yes it was weird that comparison, I fixed it and now am comparing it with the proper column. But still got the error.

Comment: @xMrShadyx You could also use *text blocks*, which are available since Java 15. They'll make your queries easier to read

Comment: @MCEmperor unfortunately still same error, I do start wondering and in posts, I've read that there few fake errors that occur with JPA Queries, is it possible to be this?

Comment: Show your latest attempt in the question, as you may have missed a space. It also helps to put in the full error, as parsers sometimes show more on where the problem lies within the string, and the stack itself can help others figure out what part of processing might find issues, so point at where to look in the string. Also note, you've duplicate the "r.people >= ?3" in the query unnecessarily - it only needs to be there once, ie "where (r.people >= ?3) and ( (x) or (y) or (z))". Simplifying the query will help figure out where issues may reside.

Answer (score 0):

You must add a space before each end quote in the query string so it can be parsed properly,try it this way:

```
  @Query(value = "SELECT r FROM Room r " +
    "WHERE (r.people >= ?3 AND r.id NOT IN (SELECT rr.room_id FROM Reservation rr)) " +
    "OR (r.people >= ?3 AND r.id IN (SELECT rr.room_id FROM Reservation rr " +
    "WHERE (rr.start_date NOT BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2) AND (rr.end_date NOT BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2))) " +
    "OR (r.people >= ?3 AND r.id IN (SELECT COUNT (rr.room_id) FROM Reservation rr " +
    "WHERE (rr.start_date BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2) AND (rr.end_date BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2) " +
    "GROUP BY rr.room_id " +
    "HAVING COUNT(rr.room_id) < r.count " +
    "ORDER BY r.id))")
```

and maybe reconsider the parenthesis ,Hope this helps !